# eslint doesn't pull in extends rules properly

Tags: node.js, eslint

I have a package of custom rules which I want to pull in (`eslint-config-common`), then use an `.eslintrc` file to override some of them.

```
extends: common
rules:
    no-invalid-this: 0 # override a rule in common
```

If I run it directly, it all works as expected:

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint src/**/*.js
```

Though if I run it as an `.sh` file or through an NPM script like `lint: eslint src/**/*.js`, it doesn't pull in the extends rules. It only runs using the rules found directly in `.eslintrc`. In my case, that's really bad since my `.eslintrc` is generally just turning off or down rules I don't want to use.

I've run it with `DEBUG:eslint:*` and it finds and loads the proper extends file, it just doesn't seem to apply the rules.

I found a bug similar to this, which they seem to say is fixed: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/2754

This bug seems similar, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if there is still a bug.

I'm using the latest version of eslint `3.17.1`

Comment: Can you try using `eslint --print-config any_js_file` and see if the rules from `common` are displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I was using a glob without wrapping it in quotation marks. It seems like NPM chewed on it a bit and it seems like it only went down as deep as one directory.

Instead of this:

```
"script": {
    "lint": "eslint path/to/code/**/*.js"
}
```

Use this:

```
"script": {
    "lint": "eslint 'path/to/code/**/*.js'"
}
```